# How to format Tab label in Android?

Tags: android

I use TabLayout with tabs in MaterialDesign style. It works OK but the third tab  gets ugly formatting ("Requests"). See pics:
[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aSz6.png)

[Need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwPvO.png)

How to make formatting as on the second pic instead of the first pic?

Answer (score 0):

I think you made

```
app:tabMode="fixed"
```

make it

```
app:tabMode="scrollable"
```